# Argument concatenation in zsh excludes certain letters

Tags: shell, zsh, string-concatenation

I'm using `zsh` on Arch Linux. I have enabled `setopt extendedglob` & `setopt sh_word_split`. I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

old_IFS="$IFS"
IFS='|'

files_to_exclude="$*"

IFS=old_IFS

cmd="rm -f -- ./^("
cmd+=$files_to_exclude
cmd+=")"

echo $cmd
```

When the arguments given to this script contain any of: `d`, `l`, `o`, `F`, `I` or `S`, they are not printed to the console. Why is that and how can I force `zsh` to print them?

Here's what I tested against:

```
./script_name a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I
J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```

Comment: You're using `/bin/sh`, not `zsh`...

Comment: I was mistaken thinking that `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `zsh`, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: On many systems `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `zsh`. When it's invoked as `sh`, the program [tries to emulate](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Invocation.html#Compatibility) the Bourne shell, which is very different from `zsh`.

Comment: In general, the executable for the Z-Shell (like many other shells) may behave differently depending how the executable file is named. For instance, if you would rename `zsh` to `-zsh` (or use a symlink), the behaviour will also change slightly. Don't forget that all programs get their own name as first argument, and can adapt their behaviour correspondingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a typo

```
- IFS=old_IFS
+ IFS=$old_IFS
```

Comment: That was it. Silly omission, thank you. The missing letters correspond to the string `old_IFS`